# Pine Script not working. Condition does not seem to work

Tags: pine-script

The script below always gives back the color red for my label colors. What am I doing wrong here?
Any feedback appreciated (pretty new to pine).

```
study("Info Labels", overlay = true)

// Variables and Conditions
ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)
ema34 = ema(close, 34)
ema34h = ema(high, 34)

sc1 = ema8 >= ema13
sc2 = ema13 > ema21
sc3 = ema21 > ema34
sc4 = close > ema34h

colorlabel1 = sc1 ? color.green : color.red
colorlabel2 = sc4 ? color.green : color.red
var label1 = label.new(bar_index, high, text = "8:13:21", style = label.style_label_lower_right, color = 
colorlabel1, size = size.small)


var label2 = label.new(bar_index, low, text = "Wave   ", style = label.style_label_lower_left, color = colorlabel2, size = size.small)


label.set_xy(label1, bar_index[1], high[1] + atr(21))
label.set_xy(label2, bar_index[1], high[1] + atr(21))
```

Comment: Your question title is too unspecific.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your labels with the `var` keyword.
That means that those variables are only initialized once, on the first bar.
On that first bar, both `sc1` and `sc4` conditions are false, so the label is created with color `red` and never changes again.

The conditions `colorlabel1` and `colorlabel2` change correctly.
You just have to update the color of the label to reflect that.
Just like you're setting the position of the label with `label.set_xy()`, you can also set the color with `label.set_color()`.

You can read more about how `var` works in the manual, under [Expressions, declarations and statements](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/language/Expressions_declarations_and_statements.html)

This will work as you intended.

```
//@version=4
study("Info Labels", overlay = true)

// Variables and Conditions
var label1 = label.new(bar_index, high, text = "8:13:21", style = label.style_label_lower_right, size = size.small)
var label2 = label.new(bar_index, low,  text = "Wave   ", style = label.style_label_lower_left,  size = size.small)

ema8 = ema(close, 8)
ema13 = ema(close, 13)
ema21 = ema(close, 21)
ema34 = ema(close, 34)
ema34h = ema(high, 34)

sc1 = ema8 >= ema13
sc2 = ema13 > ema21
sc3 = ema21 > ema34
sc4 = close > ema34h

colorlabel1 = sc1 ? color.green : color.red
colorlabel2 = sc4 ? color.green : color.red

label.set_xy(label1, bar_index[1], high[1] + atr(21))
label.set_xy(label2, bar_index[1], high[1] + atr(21))

label.set_color(label1, colorlabel1)
label.set_color(label2, colorlabel2)
```